# Debugging tests in play

Tags: java, debugging, testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having issues when trying to debug a test which fails in Play.

At first I couldn't make it hit a break point, which turned out to be caused by the forking of a new JVM which happens when testing, so I found out I need to add:

```
javaOptions in Test ++= Seq(
    "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9998"
)
```

to the `build.sbt` file.

Now it hits the break point when I start the debugger (I'm using IntelliJ) but the problem is that it won't let me start the debugger before it starts the tests.

If I use `play debug` then play starts and opens the socket (9999) and then I can start the debugger and only then in the play console start my app (using run), but I can't do the same with the tests..
Once I use `play test` the tests start so I have to start the debugger after the tests started running.

Is there any way around this?
Thanks!

Comment: Change to `suspend=yes`

Comment: oh my, that was WAY easier than I anticipated! now I feel stupid. thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it which will hopefully help others.

Change the build.sbt or build.scala to remove the default option of forking each test. Add the line **Keys.fork in (Test) := false**

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
    Keys.fork in (Test) := false
)
```

I start my play session (I am now using activator) with the following command which I store as an alias.

```
'JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`; JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xloggc:gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -server -Xmx2g -Dhttps.port=9443" activator -jvm-debug 9999'
```

This way you can start play in debug mode and attach the idea to the remote server. In intelliJ you add

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999
```

And set the port in the above case its **localhost 9999**

The reason I like doing it this way is you start the play server once and attach the ide to the remote server. You can then run tests via the console and it will hit your breakpoints, no need to restart and attach the ide for each test.